# Bootstrap popover doesn't show href links

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, popover

the popover pop's but I don't see the links - just the text, i am not sure what is wrong here:

```
<a class="sharepopover" data-original-title="Share the MMS to your groups" data-placement="top" data-content="
        &lt;div&gt;&lt;br/&gt;

            &lt;a&nbsp;href='http://gruppu.com/share/1#2'&gt;&nbsp;ludek&nbsp;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;br/&gt;

            &lt;a&nbsp;href='http://gruppu.com/share/1#3'&gt;&nbsp;kunda&nbsp;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;br/&gt;

            &lt;a&nbsp;href='http://gruppu.com/share/1#4'&gt;&nbsp;testik&nbsp;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;br/&gt;

        &lt;/div&gt;">Share</a>
```

And here is how I initialize the popover:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
      //  $("#sharepopover").popover({html: true, trigger: "click"});
      $('html').click(function(e) {
    $('.sharepopover').popover('hide');
});

$('.sharepopover').popover({
    html: true,
    trigger: 'manual'
}).click(function(e) {
    $(this).popover('toggle');
    e.stopPropagation();
});
    });
</script>
```

Update:

without escaping the html in the data-content the popover works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to diplay HTML content in the popover. Refer this **[demo JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/3GPgh/1/)**

HTML :

```
<button class="btn btn-default" data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="popover" data-container="body" type="button" data-original-title="" data-content='<a href="#">This is link</a><br><a href="#"><b>&quot;This is link 2&quot;</b></a>' data-trigger="click" id="example"> Click to Popover bottom</button>
```

JS:

```
$('#example').popover({
    html:true//,
    //content:'<a href="#">This is link</a>'
});
```